# Wordpress Ajax returning 0

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I hope you can help.
The following code in functions.php is returning 0.

```
function removeItems(){
echo "hello";
die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_removeItem', 'removeItems');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_removeItem', 'removeItems'); 

function remove_item(){
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("body").delegate(".remove_one","click",function(){
            var cart_key = jQuery(this).data("cart_key");
            jQuery.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                data: {action: "removeItem"},
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>';
}

add_action('wp_head', 'remove_item');
```

The common error I can find is not including:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_removeItem', 'removeItems');
```

...but I've added that in.

```
action=removeItem
```

is being added in the console.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Mark

Answer (score 1):

If an action is not specified, admin-ajax.php will exit, and return 0 in the process. This means your frontend has fire an action which Wordpress not recognizing. Wordpress cannot find your wp_ajax_xxx action. You may have specified this action, but remember to load this file, so that it is being called.

Summary:

1. In your plugin file/themes, remember to load the file where the

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_removeItems', 'removeItems');  
function removeItems() {     
        ...;     
       echo json_encode($array);    
}
```

2. Call them from your front-end

```js
(function($){  
var  ret     = true,  
  ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',  
  data    = {  
   'action': 'removeItems',  
  };   

$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {  
    console.log(response);  
  });  
})(jQuery);
```